# Gerrit add a new button

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

Is there a way to add a new button on a gerrit patch sets. I want to have an ability to deploy a gerrit patch set onto a staging environment, so i wish to plugin gerrit with a button/link to jenkins.

Comment: Did you end up finding information on this? I've been looking at the cookbook-plugin, but I have spent a lot of time on this without success.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Gerrit's [cookbook-plugin](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins%2Fcookbook-plugin). IIRC it contains an example, how to extend the UI.