# Add a custom button in Gerrit change UI

Tags: gerrit

I would like to add a button (or a link) in the Gerrit change UI.

The purpose for this button is to extend the Gerrit UI for a specific copyright review by external reviewers (not part of the regular development team).

The idea is that clicking on this button would show up a dialog with options for severity level for the change (Trivial, Low, High). The user would select an appropriate level, and proceed further. It should then send an email with severity level and changes in the review to a predefined list.

I have added a custom label in the Gerrit review UI. The external reviewer can then give either -1 or +1 on the review.

Is this kind of customization possible in Gerrit UI?

I have looked at answer from [gerrit-add-a-new-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119915/gerrit-add-a-new-button), but couldn't find a definite answer.

Can someone provide a more detailed answer?
I use Gerrit normally for reviews, but don't know the advanced customization features associated with it.

Thanks for help in advance.